# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 3(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, computational-mathematics

$$\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 3(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})}$$
someone please help i’m not sure how to compute this. i’ve tried to do it this way:$$\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 3(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})} = \frac {1-1/7^{4x} }{1+ 1/21^{4x}} $$

$$\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 3(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})}
= \dfrac {\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } 1-1/7^{4x} }{ \lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } 1+ 1/21^{4x} }$$
 but that’s defiantly wrong

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $\lim x→∞ \frac{7^2x +7^-2x}{3(7^2x - 7^-2x)} $ sorry if this doesn’t work i’m on a phone don’t have a laptop

Comment: Write `$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{7^{2x} +7^{-2x}}{3(7^{2x }- 7^{-2x})}$` for $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{7^{2x} +7^{-2x}}{3(7^{2x }- 7^{-2x})}$.

Comment: What's with all these people with limit questions on their phone?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\frac13 \frac{7^{2x} + 7^{-2x}}{7^{2x} - 7^{-2x}}  
&= \frac13 \frac{7^{2x}(7^{2x} + 7^{-2x})}{7^{2x}(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})} \\
&= \frac13 \frac{7^{4x} + 1}{7^{4x} - 1} \\
&= \frac13 \frac{(7^{4x} -1) + 2}{7^{4x} - 1} \\
&= \frac13 \Big(1 + \frac{2}{7^{4x} - 1}\Big) \\
&= \frac13 + \frac{2}{3(7^{4x} - 1)}
\end{align}$$
Now, what happens if $x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: wow this is really confusing

Comment: You got it? :))

Comment: why is the answer not lim→∞[1/3+2⋅7^−2/3(7^2−7^−2)]

Comment: I edited my answer. But yeah, it is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Put the constant outside of the limit:
$$
\begin {align}
l=&\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty }\color{blue}{\frac 1 3} \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ (7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})} \\
l=&\color{blue}{ \frac 1 3}\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 7^{2x} - 7^{-2x}} \\
l =& \frac 1 3\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {\color{blue}{7^{2x}}( 1+ 7^{-4x}) }{ \color{blue}{7^{2x}} (1 - 7^{-4x})} \\
l =& \frac 1 3\lim\limits_{ x \to \infty } \frac {\color{blue}{} 1+ 7^{-4x} }{ \color{blue}{} 1 - 7^{-4x}} \\
l=&\frac  1 3
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that
$$\coth x = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}, \quad\implies\quad \frac{7^{2 x}+7^{-2 x}}{7^{2 x}-7^{-2 x}} = \frac{e^{(2\ln 7)x}+e^{-(2\ln 7)x}}{e^{(2\ln 7) x}-e^{-(2\ln 7) x}}=\coth((2\ln7)x). $$
Knowing the behavior of $\coth$ at infinity, that is
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \coth x = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\tanh x} = 1, $$
you immediately get $L = 1/3$.

Comment: +1 for the original answer.

Comment: @Isham Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In that limes, $x\to\infty$ is equivalent to $7^{2x}\to\infty$, hence:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac {7^{2x} +7^{-2x} }{ 3(7^{2x} - 7^{-2x})}
= \lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac {z +z^{-1}}{ 3(z - z^{-1})}
= \frac13\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac {z^2+1}{z^2 - 1}
= \frac13
$$